# How to make a date other than the date of today's disabled by bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How do I prevent other dates are disabled, except the date of this day I use bootstrap datepicker, please solution.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tanggal').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            autoclose:true,
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span> 
        </div> <!-- end class input-group-addon -->
        <input type="text" id ="tanggal" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Pilih Tanggal" style="width:20%;" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Something like this?](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled)

Comment: I want that when the textbox is clicked, the date automatically today's date is colored, whereas today's date other than on disabled

Answer (score 1):

The following code will disable all dates other than today.

```
$('#tanggal').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose:true,
    startDate: "today",
    endDate: "today",
});
```

Please see the following documentation for more info:

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate

Here is a JSFiddle that I was using to investigate. http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/12661/

Comment: I applaud you simply because I could not understand what the question was.

Comment: I'm not completely confident that I did understand the question, so I just stated what problem I thought he was trying to solve and gave a solution.